# Send Multiple Images Selected from one Activity to second Activity, in Recyclerview

Tags: android

I would like to send multiple images that are selected from FirstActivity, and then send it to SecondActivity, in my onCreate method (FirstActivity), i already declared that my recyclerview setAdapter as photoAdapter.

```
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(4, OrientationHelper.VERTICAL));
        photoAdapter = new PhotoAdapter(this, selectedPhotos);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(photoAdapter);
```

And onClick method in Button Send in FirstActivity to pass the images to SecondActivity as below

```
     public void send(View v){
        Intent intent=new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("ABCD",selectedPhotos)
        startActivity(intent);
        }
```

And OnCreate method in SecondActivity, I declared

```
         newRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.newRV);
         newRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(4, OrientationHelper.VERTICAL));
         Intent new = getIntent();
         new.getExtra("ABCD");
```

Program is running well, multiple images show up on FirstActivity RecyclerView, but when I click button "Send", there is no Images send to the SecondActivity RecyclerView. how could I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can send an `Arraylist` of image names or id. like..

```
ArrayList<String> object = new ArrayList<String>(); //you can send image names or int resource id.
Intent intent = new Intent(Current.class, NextActivity.class);
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putSerializable("ARRAYLIST",(Serializable)object);
intent.putExtra("BUNDLE",args);
startActivity(intent);
```

and in next `Activity` get the `Bundle`

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Bundle args = intent.getBundleExtra("BUNDLE");
ArrayList<String> object = (ArrayList<String>) args.getSerializable("ARRAYLIST");
```

not tested but you can try and let me know if any issue.

Comment: the ArrayList<String> that you are talking about is already declared on my Instance Variable, as ArrayList<String> selectedPhotos = new ArrayList<>(); This 'selectedPhotos' somewhat doesnt apply on second Activity.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, helps alot, i finally get it working. Thanks @Devendra

Answer (score 0):

FirstActivity onclick method

```
 public void send(View v){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,Confirmation.class);
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putSerializable("ARRAYLIST", selectedPhotos);
        intent.putExtra("BUNDLE",args);

        startActivity(intent);

    }
```

And SecondActivity onCreate method

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle args = intent.getBundleExtra("BUNDLE");
    selectedPhotos = (ArrayList<String>)args.getSerializable("ARRAYLIST");
    newRecyclerView=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler_view3);
    photoAdapter=new PhotoAdapter(this,selectedPhotos);
    newRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(4, OrientationHelper.VERTICAL));
    newRecyclerView.setAdapter(photoAdapter);
```